# Indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

When given $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, I tried to integrate it as so:

Knowing that $\int\frac{1}{u}dx$ such that $u$ is an expression of $x$, then

$$\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx = \ln u \div \frac{du}{dx} + c$$

Applying this same idea,

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \, dx & = \ln((x+1)^2) \div (2x+2) + c \\
                             & = \frac{2\ln(x+1)}{2x+2} + c\\
                             & = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1} + c
\end{align}$$

But this isn't right, because if I integrate it using the "proper" way,

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \, dx & = -\frac{1}{x+1} + c
\end{align}$$

Which is odd. I know the second answer is correct, but why is the first one incorrect?

**EDIT**
How I got the following

$$\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx = \ln u \div \frac{du}{dx} + c$$

is as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(x)) & = \frac{1}{x} \\ \\
\text{Let }u\text{ be an expression of }x \\ \\
\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(u)) & = \frac{d}{du}(\ln(u)) \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \\
                     & = \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}
\end{align}$$
So, conversely,

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx & = \int \frac{1}{u} \, du \div \frac{du}{dx} \\
                       & = \ln u \div \frac{du}{dx} + c
\end{align}$$

Comment: you invent a new method!

Comment: where did you get the first formula?????

Comment: I think you mean $\int \frac{1}{u}\,du= \ln\lvert u\rvert + C$. Your formula does not hold if $u$ is not a linear function of $x$. More generally, it is true that $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx= \ln\lvert f(x)\rvert + C$ (provided $f(x) \neq 0$), but that derivative in the numerator is (up to scalar) absolutely essential.

Comment: @Szeto I added how I got the first formula

Comment: You do know that $\int (f(x)\cdot g(x))\,dx \neq (\int f(x)\,dx)\cdot g(x)$ in general, right?

Comment: @minimalrho Yes, if I could do that, then I could just $\int 1 \, dx \div \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ :)

Comment: I say this because you are doing this in the second equality of your "converse" step.

Comment: $$\int\left(\frac1udu\div\frac{du}{dx}\right) \ne\left(\int\frac1udu\right)\div\frac{du}{dx}$$ unless $\frac{du}{dx}$ is a constant.

Comment: @bof Wait so $\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx \neq \int(\frac{1}{u})\, du \div \frac{du}{dx}$? Does it equal to $\int(\frac{1}{u}du \div \frac{du}{dx})$ then?

Comment: Try some simple example, like $u=\frac1x$ or $u=x^2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct rule is
$$\int \frac{u'}{u} \, dx = \ln u + c$$
So if you dont have the $u'$ term you multiply and divide by $u'$
So you'll get $$\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx =\frac{u'}{u'} ×\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx$$
And you enter the term $u'$ in the numerator inside the integral if possible and you complete as above to get $$\int \frac{1}{u} \, dx =\frac{1}{u'} .\int \frac{u'}{u} \, dx =\frac{dx}{du}.ln u +c$$

But here it is NOT possible since $u'=2(x+1)$ i.e. $u'$ contains the variable $x$ that cannot be entered inside the integral.

So, your rule is valid when $u'$ does not contain the variable we are integrating about, here $x$.

Answer (score 0):

To check
$$\int f(x)\,dx=g(x)+c$$
you should differentiate $g(x)$ and confirm that you get $f(x)$.  Trying this on your suggestion, the quotient rule gives
$$\frac d{dx}\Bigl(\frac{\ln u}{\frac{du}{dx}}\Bigr)
  =\frac{\bigl(\frac{du}{dx}\bigr)^2\frac1u-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\ln u}{\bigl(\frac{du}{dx}\bigr)^2}
  =\frac1u-\frac{\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\ln u}{\bigl(\frac{du}{dx}\bigr)^2}
  \ne\frac1u\ .$$

You are probably thinking of a formula like
$$\int\frac1{ax+b}\,dx=\frac{\ln(ax+b)}{a}+c\ .\tag{$*$}$$
This is true because the denominator on the left hand side is a constant $a$ times $x$ (plus another constant).  Although it is true that $a=\frac d{dx}(ax+b)$, this is **not** the reason for $(*)$, and using the derivative in the denominator on the right hand side is **wrong** in most cases.